# How to get list transaction detail with web3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, web3js

i want to ask about get transaction list with web3js.

i used private network, and already got some transaction before. When i check my transaction count, the result is 13 transactions.

now i want to get the transactions detail and put to my transaction history table.

```
getTransactionList(){
    let web3 = store.getState().web3.web3Instance;

    for (var i=1; i < 30; i++) {

    }

    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.accounts[0], 'latest', (err, current)=>{
      for (var i=1; i <= current; i++) {
        web3.eth.getBlock(i, (err, res) => {
          console.log(res)
        })
      }
    });
}
```

this is my function to get transaction.
and this is the log:
[image: result of transaction]

then, i check to my ganache for last transaction to make sure. But when i check from web to ganache, the transaction has is not same
[image: ganache details]

in ganache my transactionhash = `0x54f3eca75d3ff10c484caebba94f302a891802594334f4771e430a86a7f87774`

but in web browser my transactionhas = `0xa287bfeb6392f492577a15e08e94066ef8f34363dab7480fcaca49e0e7052a27`

and i didn't see the details for transaction from, to and amount

did i do wrongly or i just missed something?
thanks

Comment: You're printing out block hashes, not transaction hashes.

Comment: Also note that the transaction you're looking for is in block 25, but it looks like you're stopping at block 13  in your loop.